# Find Duplicate Entry

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2010.

I have some VBA code which creates a unique key and then looks for duplicate unique key entries. Any duplicates are coloured in red.

I need to automate this a little further. If there is a duplicate unique key, copy the information from the newest entry, and paste it into the line where the original entry is. I then want the newest entry deleted.

The unique key is a concat of the customer name and the date the file was created. There will only ever be at most one duplicate entry per customer and that will be because the date the file was last updated has changed. I need the duplicate concat entry with the newest date to copy the info over the top of the entry with the oldest date on it then delete the original newest date entry. This is because we have other checks that have been completed further along the sheet that we need to keep intact.

Ideally I would like for the message box to still advise how many duplicate entries were found and for the entry to remain coloured red once the copy/paste/delete has taken place to highlight the entry that has been changed.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Start of Concatenate Code
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim r As Range
  On Error Resume Next

' Tells Excel to look in column 3 (Column C) for the last one with data in it
  lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

' Tell Excel to focus on cells 4 to 5000
  For i = 4 To lRow
' Tell Excel to paste the contents of cell 4 (column D) followed by |
'  then the contents of cell 8 (column H) into cell 2 (column B)
      Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i, 11) & " | " & Cells(i, 7)
  Next i

'End of Concatenate Code

'Start of Check for Duplicates code

  Dim j As Integer
  Dim myCell As Range
  Dim myRange As Integer

  myRange = Range("A4:A5000").Count

  j = 0

  ' Select the Range
  For Each myCell In Range("B4:B5000")

      ' Check that the cells in the range are not blank
      If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B4:B5000"), myCell.Value) > 1 Then

          ' Colour the duplicate entries in red
          myCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

          j = j + 1

      End If
  Next

  MsgBox "There are " & j & " duplicates found." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "Any duplicates have been highlighted in red.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, _
    "Duplicate Entry Checker"

' End of Check for Duplicates code

End Sub
```

**Screenshot of spreadsheet**
[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** 
OP was getting `Error 9 subscript out of range`, because I used `arrySheet(i, 8)` instead of `arrySheet(i, 4)`. I was thinking that I defined the array from the range starting at column A. Simple mistake with an easy fix.

The `Dictionary` Object is the perfect candidate for duplicate checks, so that is what I went with. The code below is untested, but should work for your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Set wrkSht = Sheets("Raw Data")

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = wrkSht.Cells(wrkSht.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim arrySheet As Variant
    'get the worksheet data into an array
    arrySheet = wrkSht.Range("D1:H" & lRow).Value2

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim keyValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim dupCount As Long

    For i = LBound(arrySheet, 1) To UBound(arrySheet, 1)

        'a concatenated key consisting of the:
        'row number
        'customer's name
        keyValue = Join(Array(i, arrySheet(i, 1)), "|")

        If Not dict.Exists(keyValue) Then
            dict(keyValue) = arrySheet(i, 4) 'save the date for this unique key

        Else
            'if we make it here, then this is a duplicate customer
            'for which we want to check the date

            'If the current row's date is greater than the previouly saved date, then
            'delete the current row
            'determine the row umber for the previously saved entry
            'place the most recent date in place of the old date
            'color it red
            'increase the duplicate counter
            If arrySheet(i,4) > dict(keyValue) Then

                wrkSht.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

                rowNum = CLng(Split(keyValue, "|")(0))

                wrkSht.Cells(rowNum, "B").Value = CDate(arrySheet(i, 4))

                wrkSht.Rows(rowNum).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                dupCount = dupCount = dupCount + 1
            End If
        End If

       'clear variables
       keyValue = vbNullString: rowNum = 0
    Next i


  MsgBox "There were " & dupCount & " duplicates found." & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Any duplicates have been highlighted in red.", _
        vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Duplicate Entry Checker"

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub


CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number
    Resume CleanExit


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @rickmanalexander, I just tried your code (and changed the name of the sheet) but I get a subscript out of range error with the number 9 in the msgbox title. There must be something i have missed but i am not sure what?

Here is the code I used:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    On Error GoTo CleanFail
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Set wrkSht = Sheets("Raw Data")

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = wrkSht.Cells(wrkSht.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim arrySheet As Variant
    'get the worksheet data into an array
    arrySheet = wrkSht.Range("D1:H" & lRow).Value2

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim keyValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim dupCount As Long

    For i = LBound(arrySheet, 1) To UBound(arrySheet, 1)

        'a concatenated key consisting of the:
        'row number
        'customer's name
        keyValue = Join(Array(i, arrySheet(i, 1)), "|")

        If Not dict.Exists(keyValue) Then
            dict(keyValue) = arrySheet(i, 8) 'save the date for this unique key

        Else
            'if we make it here, then this is a duplicate customer
            'for which we want to check the date

            'If the current row's date is greater than the previouly saved date, then
            'delete the current row
            'determine the row umber for the previously saved entry
            'place the most recent date in place of the old date
            'color it red
            'increase the duplicate counter
            If arrySheet(i, 8) > dict(keyValue) Then

                wrkSht.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

                rowNum = CLng(Split(keyValue, "|")(0))

                wrkSht.Cells(rowNum, "B").Value = CDate(arrySheet(i, 8))

                wrkSht.Rows(rowNum).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

                dupCount = dupCount = dupCount + 1
            End If
        End If

       'clear variables
       keyValue = vbNullString: rowNum = 0
    Next i


  MsgBox "There were " & dupCount & " duplicates found." & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Any duplicates have been highlighted in red.", _
        vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Duplicate Entry Checker"

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub


CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number
    Resume CleanExit


End Sub
```

Comment: For future reference, please don't respond to an answer with another answer, just use the comment section. See my edit, copy and paste that code, and then run it. Since the code it deleting rows, I would make a backup copy of the file just in case something goes wrong. Let me know if the edit works for you.

Comment: Hi @rickmanalexander,

Sorry about that - total newby here :)

Comment: I've copied your new code. When I run the code I no longer receive an error but it doesn't do anything when a newer version is on the sheet. I tested it out by copying an existing line and changing the due by date plus the date it was modified. Both lines are still there after executing the code.

Would it help if I listed the column headers because I just realised I hadn't done that in my original post?

B is the unique key that this sheet needs to create by concating columns D and L. When column L changes this is when I need the code to replace the old due by date etc with the new one :)

Comment: No worries. And yeah, those columns are slightly different from what you originally mentioned. Edit your original post to include a picture of the layout of the sheet and I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Apologies @rickmanalexander, I added the image but forgot to reply to your comment to advise you of this :)